# Can someone find my Gravatar profile if they have my email address, or Gravatar URL associated with that email address?

Tags: privacy, gravatar, anonymous

Gravatar now offers profiles that are publicly visible. Let's say I have entered some info in my profile. Let's also say I have two email addresses, email1 and email2, registered with Gravatar but with different avatar images. Is there any way someone (other than Gravatar/Wordpress itself) who knows my email1 address or the corresponding Gravatar URL find my public profile, email2 address, or the corresponding Gravatar URL, or otherwise associate email1 with any of those things?

At first glance, it seems like this would not be possible without access to my Gravatar account. (This is, of course, assuming that I've not done anything obvious like put that email address on my public profile, or the email is [mygravatarusername]@[somedomain].com or something like that.) However, I wanted to get some other opinions in case I've overlooked something.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone has your email address, they can access your gravatar profile and any information you set to publicly visible.

A simple request to `https://secure.gravatar.com/{MD_5_HASH_OF_YOUR_EMAIL}.json` will return the public profile url associated to this email address.

An way around would be to set your profile to private and this will prevent others to find your information using just your email address.

Comment: Gravatar has been involved with a lot of security scandals involving stuff like this over the years. One would hope they improved some of their security practices as a result. Do you know if your answer is applicable to all accounts, even new ones?

Comment: As long as your profile is set to Public, this answer is applicable. You can set your profile to private by visiting your gravatar profile.